# Xamarin Forms slow navigating

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a search page that have a Button to navigate to another page . When I click on that Button it takes about 4 seconds to navigate .

SearchPage Command :

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    await (Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).PushAsync(new OtherPage());
});
```

OtherPage Code Behind :

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class OtherPage : ContentPage
    {
        SearchStateViewModel Model;
        public SearchEstatePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Model = new SearchStateViewModel();

            Layout.BindingContext = Model;
        }

         protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            Model.GetCities();
        }
    }
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: So have you commented out `GetCities` and tested it also why are you using `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall I comment out `GetCities` and delete `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` for the first time it takes 3 seconds and when i press back button and again press navigation button it navigate fast . only first time is slow

Comment: My gut feeling says there maybe more going on do you have any slow code in the constructor to SearchStateViewModel ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall I have commented out all code in SearchStateViewModel's constructor and still it takes about 3 seconds to navigate for first time . Is there any way to navigate to otherpage and after completely show that run some code ?

Comment: I still feel there must be more going on here. If you create a new fresh page with nothing on it, does it still take time to navigate ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall No . I have Created a new page without anything in it ant it navigates fast

Comment: Then there is something fishy with your page, something on it, something in code behind, or some code you aren't sharing (or some other quirk)... If you are 100% sure there isnt any other code affecting this path. then i would consider commenting out the xaml little by little until you find the rendering issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220835/discussion-between-mm-sh-and-michael-randall).

Comment: @MichaelRandall Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: Sorry I am not in the position to chat atm

Comment: @MichaelRandall you mean I comment out all xaml and uncommenting it part to part and test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MichaelRandall advice I have checked OtherPage's XAML and finde that the Syncfusion's components in XAML slows down the navigation .

But what what is the replacement ?

Comment: "But what what is the replacement ?" - Syncfusion is a commercial component. WHich means support. Contact them. It is their JOB to help clients. Possibly a version issue, something that gets patched or they have code advice for you. Why you even ask this question? It shows a tremendous lack of understanding about how support for commercial components works.

Comment: Please do not ask questions in the Answer box. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how Answers at Stack Overflow work.